# QField offline working with PostGIS database in a local network

Tags: qgis, postgis, qfield, qfieldsync

I am using a QGIS project connecting to PostGIS as the database where the network has no access to the internet. When I export the data using QFieldSync, a gpkg file is created in addition to the qgs file. However, when I move the two files to the Android device, the layers are not loaded and the following error occurs.[

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrS5P.jpg)

The save paths in the project properties is set to relative.
Has anybody any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: In the QField project settings, did you choose "offline editing" for these layers?

Answer (score 1):

You are now connecting Qfield with online database, if you need it offline try to change all layers status to offline editing from Qfield plugin configure current project